Decoding API headers of unknown encoding?
I'm using mitmproxy to monitor facebook messenger app traffic on my android. Firstly I had to enable whitehat settings to use it. After that I found some request headers has some unknown value in body. I'm interested in how I can decode it to readable values. I share some hedaers that may be useful and part of the body. I'm trying to decode the "message"
x-zero-eh: 2,,ARys0IQcV43i0n7eZdYJOf3-k_kr3weIUEz_R2wyWMWvqSQM6b9aQsP6hL6Bo22qWeo
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=q5RVscAPTSORepjPY7ZoY8l36AnVEDWpk4bK3f
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
x-fb-http-engine: Liger
x-fb-client-ip: True
x-fb-server-cluster: True

Part of body:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cmsg"; filename="message"Content-Type: application/octet-streamContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary.�........�[S�6.���f�O1�]Vfx��&�&�.��.�l+�.;\�p[�{e.�ۆl�Y�&<.)G���".)�.y.k�F.aJ1�.q�.��B�.�q.1�BP"].�U.��:��.4..�.��ʿ�F��\Š�\�86��@0N2������DZ ԓ(0�`��lJ.7��8{l�hh���.|.��#�p��C..8����A.1"X׈.T.�n����t�E�d����@�hH��.��#5�.&)s|.".h�Z:��!��%hS�.W�8�.�.����2h�.�T.g��'8�U���K��N.��?��[Q�ŉ�.����ut.O��$��..�� Z�4�.�..W��{�o��\�..�yz�[.�6n..ڂPD�$�..h.�(3�zRp/.��0w�>�1���ε.7c>����.���b�3R�`��f���f</ʼ\�����6R.Fc/��(n�u4��d�h#x.����L�..z���z�����Jg�)1��$�.m.-��..��O.��.�'�QCSV�g�..u�YS��n曨�..S,n�2ӈ�����ff�����.��.?��.#|�Q���X�.�.U�.�̑,�.�PF�����ع.�Ħ�PI.sl��4�j7�>.D"�C�.����.I�_�2��~.D��z���nu�������Z=ܴ���.1�����l��W���s���Da̤Yd�.�.d�D����ɜ-�.7빣0��Q�.���0�K�.�.��ͬ�h��"d���.i=n�:��&}��_..�.�).�¯�U!�ˌ�.U��Uj�++..yC�Q����6��GgkR\�ER�z.׳��1n�.IPM9.<sä9�[r�iQc.G�x8���.�.�����.g�]sܠ�fY]�.�h���Xa8A.s�).Dߌ.��.�{��...d�.����0U.Kb�.�`Ɉ.2���.�~�H�_.�U�Y{v4.����.�h#��XS��:�� ��Q.6.�P��<l�ֻ�xA�$�kuG-ڈ+8ִ�i.�_�r���g�0���V��8A!�[SƅZ�oTr��>��c��&x.���j�.��.�h.��X�wD6s|�m��FP\��F.��r��.J���N ��&78���6.$�)�o.�.3�+�4g}#%.�&öh.��X�q.�8�?�.�.�o.�� .{�ʃ�B���U...���JөP�.�.��\g�3�o.��T.�Y�.p�}.����u�l..��F'�A�=[��q���'q�nH��:���׻.+�>4�k�їխ�B&<.�n|Lz��{6��k+7��}�=\g]|0�n����A��vz�;�D����5��)ϖ�w..�!.~��,OħlY+<.�.!]���̕._C�8U���ILtZ����a�M�����w�.....��y�A..--q5RVscAPTSORepjPY7ZoY8l36AnVEDWpk4bK3f--`

I hope anybody can share any thoughts. Any information will be useful for me. Thank you.
